# Directive with js-call in the template - method does not get called

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my angular app, I have an alert-service, which handles the list of alerts. I then have a directive, which renders all the alerts to the page. I use the UI Bootstrap components.

However, the close button of the alert does not call the method:

```
.directive('someAlert', ['alertService', function (alertService){
        var templateString = '<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: templateString,
        scope: true, 
        controller: function(){
            var vm = this;

            vm.alerts = alertService.get();

            vm.closeAlert = function (index) {
                console.log('closeAlert within directive controller called');
                alertService.closeAlertIdx(index);
            }
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        replace: true
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a close method directly to the alert-instance. Then the alert.close() is working as expected. Nice solution found: [alertservice](https://gist.github.com/seyDoggy/66978b761fb8572250f7) and a slightly  [modified](https://gist.github.com/honkskillet/74338981b36931647650)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `templateString`

```
close="vm.closeAlert($index)"
```

Comment: I had that idea already before posting. However, I found out, that if I add the controllerAs name before the method in the template, and in the controller of the view which uses the directive the method is declare, it will be called. This is definitive not what I wanted.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the second sentence. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: OK, let's try: suppose we have a view 'hello.html' and the controller for this view 'hello.controller.js'. We use the controllerAs syntax with e.g. vm. When we now add the alert directive to that view, and the controllerAs name of the alert-directive is also vm, then the call from the directive (vm.close...) goes to the hello.controller.js - which is not what I want (or how it should be)

Comment: ng-repeat creates a scope for each of the iterations. That scope is not isolated and inherits prototypically from the surrounding scope. Given that your ng-repeat is on the topmost element of your template I could imagine that that is where things go wrong. I'd try to wrap the template in a surrounding div, then have the ng-repeat on a div which in turn contains the uib-alert.